# Javascript Syntax. What is this: ", (err) => { }"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't even know what to call it so not sure how to ask the question properly.  What is the operator and what is it doing?  I'm assuming its just passing a function expression as a callback, but the syntax is new to me.

**(err) =>**

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Comment: ES5 new arrow function syntax
check it here
https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

Comment: You can omit braces about `err` also: `err => console.error(err)`

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov ES6, not ES5.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read up on ES6 features, since you are likely to encounter them more and more, including not only arrow functions, but also template strings and shorthand object literals to name just a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a so-called [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It is a short form for defining function expressions. Hence,

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

is basically similar to:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Anyway, there is big difference bitween the syntaxes: While `function` creates a new scope for `this`, an arrow function re-uses the outer scope. Hence, in a callback defined using the `function` keyword you may need something such as

```
const that = this;
```

to preserve the outer scope, using an arrow function you don't need that. Please note that this also means that you are not able to use `bind` with an arrow function (i.e., it's not possible to redefine `this` for an arrow function (okay, to be true, you *can* use it, but the first parameter won't have any effect)).

Apart from that, please note that you can omit the parentheses around the parameter if there is only one. Hence, instead of

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

you may also write:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Anyway, this only works if there is only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is ES6's arrow function (or lambda) syntax. Check out [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

It is indeed a callback, that will accept an argument named `err`.

In your case it is semantically equivalent to the following :

```
function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
}
```

Comment: It is semantically **not** equivalent. Arrow functions deal differently with `this`.

Comment: ...and function-scoped variables don't scope to them.

Comment: Woops, you're right. I won't go into the details but have edited my answer to specify it is only equivalent in this specific case.

Comment: @metarmask What do you mean by *function-scoped variables don't scope to them*?

Comment: @torazaburo `var flag = true;` creates a function-scoped variable. Those variables can only be accessed from within the function they are in. `let flag = false;` creates a block-scoped variable which can only be accessed from the block it is declared in (or blocks within that block). Arrow functions create a block.